# Insert input into a drupal form programmatically

Tags: api, drupal, forms

How can i populate the input field programmatically in drupal form API?
Let me illustrate, consider the following example

```
function form(){
return drupal_get_form('myform');
}
function myform($form_state){
$form['name'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'$title' => 'Name: ',
 );
$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => 'Save',
 );
 return $form;
}
function myform_submit($form,&$form_state){
$form_id = 'myform';
$form_state['values']['name'] = 'Hello World';
drupal_execute($form_id,$form_state);
}
```

Here, when submit event occurs, instead of getting the values populated, i get the white blank screen of death on the screen. Is something wrong with my syntax??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper way to use drupal_execute.  However, there are other problems with the way you're handling that form: try attaching a submit and validate function to the form.  When you do that, you will also need to move the drupal_execute out of the submit function (which may be causing the problem you're having now).  If you need to save data, you need to use the DB abstraction layer, drupal_write_record, or one of the existing hooks.

```
$form_state = array(
  'submitted' => true,
  'values' => array(
    'name' => 'Hello World',
    'op' => t('Save'),
    'submit' => t('Save'),
    'form_id' => 'myform',
  ),
);

drupal_execute('myform', $form_state);
```